# Moving a motor with an arduino and a photo-sensor

Tags: python, loops, arduino, arduino-uno

So I started using an Arduino kit I bought recently, and have been attempting to make a motor move (for now) before I go onto more complex things.

The point of my little project in the future will be for the Arduino to sense light from near my window at night. From there it will hopefully turn a motor that hits my alarm clock. Though for now I simply want to get the motor moving when it sees light, and off once it stops seeing light, as I can add an automatic turn off after a few seconds later.

Here is the current code:

```
const int motorPin = 9;
const int sensorPin = 10;
int lightLevel, high = 0, low = 1023;

void setup()
{
  // Set up the motor pin to be an output:
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);

  // Set up the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  motormoveLevel = analogRead(sensorPin);
  manualTune(); 
  analogWrite(motorPin, lightLevel);
}    


void manualTune()
{
  lightLevel = map(lightLevel, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  lightLevel = constrain(lightLevel, 0, 255);
}
```

It does not compile, however the codes I derived it from do, here is one that turns on the motor for a few seconds then turns it off intermittently:

```
const int motorPin = 9;

void setup()
{
  // Set up the motor pin to be an output:
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);

  // Set up the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
   motorOnThenOff();
}


// This function turns the motor on and off like the blinking LED.
// Try different values to affect the timing.
void motorOnThenOff()
{
  int onTime = 3000;  // milliseconds to turn the motor on
  int offTime = 3000; // milliseconds to turn the motor off

  digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH); // turn the motor on (full speed)
  delay(onTime);                // delay for onTime milliseconds
  digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);  // turn the motor off
  delay(offTime);               // delay for offTime milliseconds
}
```

And this code turns an led on and off based on the photosensor:

```
 const int sensorPin = 0;
 const int ledPin = 9;

 int lightLevel, high = 0, low = 1023;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  lightLevel = analogRead(sensorPin);
  manualTune(); 
  analogWrite(ledPin, lightLevel);
}


void manualTune()
{
  lightLevel = map(lightLevel, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  lightLevel = constrain(lightLevel, 0, 255);
}
```

So basically, I'm trying to use these two pieces of code to make the motor move based on whether it senses light. My 'Frankenstein's-monster' isn't compiling and as such, I would like help in combing the two codes to make the motor move when light hits the photosensor, and not move when it is covered (I already know how to wire it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t analogRead on pin 0. You must use A0-A5 (14-19)

Comment: so how would that look like in the context of the code?

Comment: Change ‘sensorPin = 10’ to ‘sensorPin = A0’ and use that pin for the sensor.